# RTK Query передача аргументов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Как можно передать в query функцию несколько аргументов ?  На данный момент он не видит аргумент id = undefined .

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'api',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001' }),
    tagTypes: ['Person'],
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getPerson: builder.query({
            query: () => '/person',
            providesTags: ['Person']
        }),
        getOnePerson: builder.query({
            query: id => `/person/${id}`,
            providesTags: ['Person']
        }),
        createMessage: builder.mutation({
            query: (mess,id) => { //Сюда нужно передать 2 аргумента 
                return {
                    url: `/person/${id}`,
                    method: 'PATCH',
                    body: mess
                }

            },
            invalidatesTags: ['Person']
        }),

    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если передать можно только 1 аргумент , то при вызове мы передаём объект с набором свойств , а в функции query уже деструктуризируем и подставляем куда угодно .

```
createMessage: builder.mutation({
            query: ({mess,id}) => { //Сюда нужно передать 2 аргумента 
                return {
                    url: `/person/${id}`,
                    method: 'PATCH',
                    body: mess
                }

            }
```